# jersey calling one resource from another to resuse code

Tags: java, rest, resources, jersey

I am trying to refactor my code to make re-use existing code but wanted some suggestions as to how this should be done in the best possible way using REST resources (Jersey in this case).

I have a resource that deals with Domains. Such methods in this resource include getting a domain, getting multiple domains, and posting for bulk gets (too many to use a GET).

However, I also have a resouce that does the same for URLs. Except that what I do here is to extract the domains from the URL and effectively perform the same logic that I do with the DomainResource class as once I have the domain from the URL, I need to execute the exact same lookups. However instead of re-using the existing DomainResource methods, I am duplicating and calling the same methods in my URLResouce class.

So is it better to have duplication in this case and keep the resources separate, or is it possible (bad/good preactice) to call one resource from another, in the case, the URLResouce would delegate to the DomainResource? How does this sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common code should be in a utility class.  Each of your resources (by which I think you man the methods annotated with @GET) would not normally call each other.  I would put a `fetchDomains` method in a utility class.  Then the controller/service/resource method for getting domains would call that utility method directly, and the controller/service/resource method for getting domains from URLs would first extract the domain then call the utility method.

Answer (score 0):

```
So is it better to have duplication in this case
```

No, In any case Because duplication reduce your oops concept.So please try to keep common code in separate class.